# Current flow on Load (A)

Tags: voltage, current

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwgb9E.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

From my analysis, and applying circuit theory, I find that Load(A) will have current flowing equal to 0.1Amps due to the PS, and the induced V1&V2 cancel out, without the use of a diode. However, there cannot be any induced-current from the induced-voltage source correct? They cancel out before that happens?

Comment: I've noticed that in all your 53 questions on SE.EE you have never marked one "accepted". Are you aware how to do this or is there some other reason?

Comment: No, not aware at all, how would I do that?

Comment: You should really read the page rules if you will, before you register... Take a look at here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @Key - You press the check mark button under the up/down vote arrows to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be analysed because you have an anomaly where the two induced voltages (net effect zero volts) is placed across a voltage source of 10 volts. This will cause infinite current to flow and makes it non-analysable.

Even if the two induced voltages were additive or anything that resulted in a net voltage other than 10V it produces infinite current.

With a voltage source (as shown) across a 100 ohm resistor, this part of the circuit can be taken in isolation and the current will be 0.2 amps.